# MySQL new installation: Access denied for user

Tags: linux, mysql, password

Before installation

```
wolf@Linux:~$ service mysql status
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
wolf@Linux:~$
```

Installation ...

```
wolf@Linux:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
```

After installation

```
wolf@Linux:~$ service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-05-29 11:33:26 +08; 10s ago
 Main PID: 4219 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 28 (limit: 1129)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─4219 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Mei 29 11:33:26 Linux1 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Mei 29 11:33:26 Linux1 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
wolf@Linux:~$
```

Still can't access it

```
wolf@Linux:~$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'wolf'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
wolf@Linux:~$
```

/var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2020-05-29T04:29:04.188484Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'wolf'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Even with root user

```
wolf@Linux:~$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
wolf@Linux:~$ 

wolf@Linux:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
wolf@Linux:~$
```

/var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2020-05-29T04:30:01.312977Z 4 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
2020-05-29T04:30:15.223701Z 5 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Reset the root password

```
wolf@Linux:~$ sudo mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
wolf@Linux:~$
```

no new log at /var/log/mysql/error.log when resetting the new password

but didn't work too

```
wolf@Linux:~$ mysql -u root -pNEWPASSWORD
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
wolf@Linux:~$
```

/var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2020-05-29T04:32:35.609239Z 8 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Attempt to access it without password also didn't work

```
wolf@Linux:~$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 5489
wolf@Linux:~$ 2020-05-30T03:43:42.913712Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2020-05-30T03:43:42.916500Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2020-05-30T03:43:42.918902Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
wolf@Linux:~$
```

no new log at /var/log/mysql/error.log when `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

**Update** /var/log/mysql/error.log during installation

```
wolf@Linux:/var/log/mysql$ tail -F error.log 
2020-05-30T04:28:13.132939Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-05-30T04:28:13.132959Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2020-05-30T04:28:13.133002Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2020-05-30T04:28:13.133009Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2020-05-30T04:28:13.133027Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2020-05-30T04:28:13.137509Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-05-30T04:28:13.137601Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-30T04:28:13.138071Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200530 12:28:13
2020-05-30T04:28:13.138126Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Have you ever started mysql ? `systemctl start mysql`

Comment: @GillesQuenot, yes ... see `After installation` note above. It's already started automatically after installation

Comment: What is error log in /var/log/mysql/error.log , when "sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables" exit?

Try login using following options : 
1) sudo mysql -uroot 
2) mysql -u mysql 
Also check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895163/how-to-find-out-the-mysql-root-password